# Wait immediately after Releasing mutex, switching threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex, semaphore

Suppose that I have this mutex (or semaphore) called `Mutex1`

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim Mutex1 = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
```

Will following code always work as my expectations?

**Thread A**

```
await Mutex1.WaitAsync(); // wait in thread "A" until thread "B" releases mutex
```

**Thread B**

```
Mutex1.Release();
await Mutex1.WaitAsync(); // thread A should continue and thread B should wait.
```

Is `Mutex1.Release` in thread **B** always guaranteed to cause continuation in thread **A**?

My guess answer is no, because before thread **A** continues, thread **B** may wait again and since "waiting threads" are not queued, thread **B** may continue again instead of thread **A**. am I right?

---

The safe approach that I'm currently using is with additional field called `Mutex2`.

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim Mutex2 = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
```

**Thread A**

```
await Mutex1.WaitAsync(); // wait in thread "A" until thread "B" releases mutex
```

**Thread B**

```
Mutex1.Release();
await Mutex2.WaitAsync(); // notice Mutex TWO
```

Now I'm sure that switching between threads is handled correctly, but I wanted to know if I can save one field and use first approach safely or not. note that this operation is wrapped in lock so its single threaded and safe.

(for those who are curios this is the part of application for making synchronized communication between two apps using UWP app services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx we have:

> If multiple threads are blocked, there is no guaranteed order, such as FIFO or LIFO, that controls when threads enter the semaphore.

So, to me, this says that the slim semaphores do *not* queue up requests.

And, that your first approach has a race condition. That is, thread B can release the mutex and *immediately* reacquire it, locking out thread A for an indeterminate amount of time.

So, you probably have to use your two semaphore approach. Or, use a different synchronization primitive that supports a [fair] queue of waiters.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using this, you should try using a `AutoResetEvent`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx

That will do what you want.